# UILabel not displaying text when background image is set

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I tried to set a background image to a label in UITableViewCell,But while running ,only the background image is displayed in label,text is not displayed.

This is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

    // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageView *preparationLabelBg = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbg.jpeg"]];
    [cell.preparationLabel addSubview:preparationLabelBg];
    cell.preparationLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.preparationLabel sendSubviewToBack:preparationLabelBg];
    [cell.preparationLabel setOpaque:NO];

}

[cell.preparationLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:14]];

// Configure the cell.
if (btnselected==1)
{
    cell.preparationLabel.text = [recipe.ingredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
 cell.preparationLabel.text = [recipe.preparation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
```

}

Why text is not displayed here?Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code,

```
theLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbg.jpeg"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not add background image to UILable instead add background image to tableCell as subnview or add background image as `[cell.contentview addSubview:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbg.jpeg"]]`

Also use PNG instead of JPEG/JPG. Apple prefer PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting background to the `lable` put one `ImageView` at the back of `lable` and then set the image to that `ImageView`. It will work.